# Stop+ Ving and Stop+ to+infinitive?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

I have two questions here:

1. To which action we can use ***Stop + gerund***?
2. And to which action we can use ***Stop + to + infinitive***?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

***[Stop](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stop_1):***

> - ***Notice the difference between stop doing something and stop to do something*** - *We stopped taking pictures means ‘We were no longer taking pictures.’;We stopped to take pictures means ‘We stopped what we were doing so that we could start taking pictures.’*

(Oxford Learner's Dictionary)

Compare:

***He stopped to look at*** the window shop. (He was walking and he stopped in order to look at the window shop)

***He stopped looking at*** the windows shop. (He was looking at the window shop  and decided not to  look at it any longer)

Answer (score 6):

We use the -ing form after stop to indicate that an action or event is no longer continuing:

> It’s stopped raining. Let’s go for a walk. (It was raining, but not any more.)

We use the to-infinitive after stop to indicate that someone stops doing something in order to do something else:

> On the way to London, we stopped to look at an old castle. (We were travelling, then we stopped our journey in order to look at the castle.)